# how to capture onclick for wicket jquery ui spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket

How can I capture the onclick event for the up & down buttons on a spinner component from JQuery?

I am able to capture the onchange for the associated textfield with the following code, but the up & down spinner buttons are not triggering the event:

```
                Spinner<Integer> psbBudget = new Spinner<>("psbBudget", new PropertyModel(psb,"psbBudget"), Integer.class);
                psbBudget.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
                    @Override
                    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
                        Integer inputS = (Integer) getFormComponent().getConvertedInput();
                        BigDecimal spinnerTime = BigDecimal.valueOf(inputS);
                        unallocatedTimeMap.put(psb, unallocatedTimeMap.get(psb).subtract(spinnerTime));
                        art.add(budgetListViewContainer);
                    }
                });
                listItem.add(psbBudget);

                li.add(new Label("remainingBudgetLabel", new Model(unallocatedTimeMap.get(psb))));
```

Just to make it more difficult on myself, this spinner is contained in a ListView as the number of budget items is variable.  I am getting the remainingBudgetLabel to reflect the changes that are made within the text field, but not the changes made using the spinner buttons!

I have started exploring injecting my own javascript with the following lines:

```
        // behavior to capture changes made using spinner buttons (doesn't work!!!)
        add(new Behavior() {
            @Override
            public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
                super.renderHead(component, response);
                response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('.ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only').click(function() {$(this).siblings('input').change();})"));
            }
        });
```

Here is the relevant section of the declared html:

```
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td/>
                                        <th>Budget</th>
                                        <th>Remaining</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr wicket:id="budgetListView">
                                        <th wicket:id="budgetLabel">Budget
                                        </th><td><input wicket:id="psbBudget" type="text" style="width:3em" maxLength="2"/>
                                        </td><td wicket:id="remainingBudgetLabel"/>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

So I guess this is somewhat of a two part question:
1 - Is there any hope of this javascript injection working (I am just getting my feet wet with javascript) or is there a way to do this more correctly within Wicket?
2 - If javascript is the only way, how can I correctly find the elements when I can't control the id attribute of the generated jquery (or can I control that somehow?)?

I am using the wicket-jquery-ui 6.2.1 library with wicket 6.6.0.  Thank you.

**EDIT**

The generated html I posted previously (now removed) was from right clicking and selecting viewSource, but does not show the actual generated html from jquery.  Please see below for a screenshot from the F12 Developer Tools in IE9 that shows the generated html for the spinner includes the original `<input>` plus two generated `<a>` tags for the spinner buttons.

[image]

Comment: What if you assign your custom js for "spin" or "change" (spinner events) through Options. Haven't tried it but I can't see why it wouldn't work. This way you make sure it runs after the spinner is initialized (which I guess is the reason why it is not working for you). To set the markup id there is setMarkupId(String) on Component. There is also getMarkupId if you want to access that in your java code.

Comment: @buritos - Thanks for your suggestion, I have been intrigued by the Options object and will look into that solution.  'setMarkupId()' just sets the id for the '<input>' component and doesn't change the generated jquery (I realize now this is not appearing in the generated html, so I will include a screenshot in my edit)

Comment: @buritos - Your suggestion led me to a solution that worked for me.  I referenced the javadocs for the jquery spinner and there was a `stop()` event.  I am not sure how it works, but by putting `onstop` for the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior event I was able to capture the event and get the adjusted value in the textfield.  If you want to answer my question with something along these lines I will accept it as the answer... I just hate answering my own question.

Comment: I hate taking credit without giving a clear answer. I'm glad that my comment actually helped so please go ahead and answer with your solution and I will upvote it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I hate to answer my own question, here it is:

I was able to capture the events with the following code.  The "onchange" captures the event when someone manually enters a number in the field, the "onspinstop" captures the event after the component has been updated by clicking the up/down arrow:

```
Spinner<Integer> psbBudget = new Spinner<>("psbBudget", new Model(allocatedTimeMap.get(psb)), Integer.class);
psbBudget.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
        Integer input = (Integer) getFormComponent().getConvertedInput();
        // Do whatever with updated input //
        art.add(remainingBudgetLabel,remainingBudgetLabel.getMarkupId());
    }
}
psbBudget.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onspinstop") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
        Integer input = (Integer) getFormComponent().getConvertedInput();
        // Do whatever with updated input //
        art.add(remainingBudgetLabel,remainingBudgetLabel.getMarkupId());
    }
}
```

I was able to figure this out after looking at the [API documentation for the JQuery UI Spinner component](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/) then trying every possible combination of the event strings.  To do this correctly you have to put the string all in lowercase and add "on" string to the beginning of the event name.

One additional thing that I learned during this exercise was that I can update (I think I am actually replacing them?) individual components within a listview by calling `art.add(component, component.getMarkupId());`.  This is SO much better than what I was doing before with `listView.setList(updatedList)` and `art.add(listViewContainer);`

Answer (score 2):

I just saw this post...

Just to say that you had 2 other options:

1/ You have you own extended spinner with:

```
@Override
protected void onConfigure(JQueryBehavior behavior)
{
    super.onConfigure(behavior);

    behavior.setOption("onspinstop", this.onStopBehavior.getCallbackFunction());
    //onStopBehavior is an JQueryAjaxPostBehavior, see how AjaxDatePicker works for instance
}
```

The second option is to ask for an `AjaxSpinner`, because it makes sense, either through the github project or the google group:
https://github.com/sebfz1/wicket-jquery-ui/
http://groups.google.com/group/wicket-jquery-ui/

Best regards,
Sebastien.

Comment: Thanks sebfz1, I am not familiar with the JQueryAjaxPostBehavior class and will have to look into the docs for that.  It sounds intreguing and could help solve some other Wicket-JQueryUI problems I am having.  Regarding requesting a component via github or googlegroup, I guess I just figure if it was something usefull it would already be included, otherwise if it is something I need, I should just build it myself.  Thanks for the good points.

Comment: Hi, yes if you need to extend some components (or write your own), in particular with ajax, I suggest you lo look at JQueryAjaxPostBehavior & JQueryAjaxBehavior. The philosophy of component implementation changed a little bit in the latest version (6.7.0, publishing tonight) so docs might be not accurate for some days/weeks until I rewrite it. But here is a [sample](https://github.com/sebfz1/wicket-jquery-ui/blob/master/wicket-jquery-ui-samples/src/test/java/MyJQueryLabel.java) of a virtual component/behavior/listener/ajax-behavior corresponding to the new implementation. Enjoy :)